# Inline functions as code snippet / template

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

EDIT:
Basically I want to be able to use the following mechanism as an answer to my original question:

```
void MethodA()
{
    MethodB();

    //This code will never be reached because 'return' from the inline MethodB is executed.

    //... More code here
}

[Attribute(Inline)]
ReturnValue MethodB()
{
    return;
}
```

Of course the example above is useless on its own, more logic will be put in MethodB of course but I left it out for brevity.

**Original question:**
In a project that is already 1 year under development there is chosen to do the following. Instead of throwing exceptions, each functions returns a `ReturnValue<T>` on which a `IsSuccessFul` boolean flag lives. It is used like this

```
var methodResult = MyMethod();
if (!methodResult .IsSuccesful)
{
    return new ReturnValue<Type>(methodResult .ThrownException);
}
var value= methodResult.Value;
```

This way of calling methods is used on every public function in the project. You can image that this requires more lines of code than `var value = MyMethod();` with a generic try catch. Especially if a dozen of public functions are called in a scope.

*Please don't argue with the chosen design, I am not here to debate whether this is a good choice or not.*

What I want to know is this: Is there a way I can do this

```
var value= TryMethod(MyMethod);
```

And that the compiler, or some plugin, or whatever, transforms this precompile time to the full pattern shown earlier. My point is, if !IsSuccessFul the function should return. I could write a precompile time command that does this for me but I was hoping at some kind of snippet/template/inline way of VisualStudio itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

should be as easy as (for the **pattern** - which of course here is rather useless because it's basically the identity, only that it will recreate another `ReturnValue<T>` - so **not advised**):

```
public static ReturnValue<T> TryMethod<T>(Func<ReturnValue<T>> method)
{
   var methodResult = method();
   if (!methodResult .IsSuccesful)
       return new ReturnValue<T>(methodResult.ThrownException);

   // I can only guess at this:
   return methodResult;
}
```

but based on your usage *I think* you really **want**:

```
public static T TryMethod<T>(Func<ReturnValue<T>> method)
{
   var methodResult = method();
   if (!methodResult .IsSuccesful)
       throw methodResult.ThrownException;

   return methodResult.Value;
}
```

of course you might have to make multiple overloads (when your method takes parameters - like:

```
public static T TryMethod<T,P>(Func<P,ReturnValue<T>> method, P p)
{
   var methodResult = method(p);
   // ...
```

and you might want to put those into a static extension class and do:

```
public static T TryMethod<T>(this Func<ReturnValue<T>> method)
```

so you can write

```
var value = MyMethod.TryMethod();
```

and so on.

#### make it *Monadic*

Overall your design might not be to bad but you should consider adding the usual functor-map and mondadic-bind operations (you could even use LINQ when you do `SelectMany`) to your `ReturnValue<T>` type:

```
public static ReturnValue<B> Map<A,B>(this ReturnValue<a> v, Func<A,B> f)
{
    if (v.IsSuccesful) return new ReturnValue<B>(f(v.Value));
    return new ReturnValue<B>(v.ThrownException);
}

public static ReturnValue<B> Bind<A,B>(this ReturnValue<a> v, Func<A,ReturnValue<B>> f)
{
    if (v.IsSuccesful) return f(v.Value);
    return new ReturnValue<B>(v.ThrownException);
}
```

#### example usage of `Bind`

using this `Bind` here you can do this instead and **I think that is what you meant with scope**:

```
method().Bind(
    value => { 
        // ... whatever you want to do with value - just return a ReturnValue<> at the end 
    });
```

Comment: I think your approach is the right one, but I see one problem in your code: `Func<T> method` needs to be refactor to `Func<ReturnValue<T>> method` I guess. Otherwise the compiler would not know that `method()` results does have a Property called `IsSuccesful`

Comment: How do I exit the scope of the caller when `!IsSuccessful` using your suggestions. Maybe I did not state my question as clear as I hoped. Kind of like C macro's I guess.

Comment: Rethrowing like that isn't a great idea because the stack trace of the original exception gets blown away. Wrapping might be solution, but the original code seems like it is going to great length to avoid throwing in the first place.

Comment: @mikez really hard to change it with the design I see behind `ReturnValue`

Comment: @MikedeKlerk what do you mean by `exit the scope`? you want the wraped value (of type `T`) back and there are only two possibilities if there is none: rethrow the captured exception (as I did) or return a default value (you can change it like this if you want)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Like mikez said, the code is avoiding to throw exceptions at all times. So rethrowing is no option, returning a default value neither because then I would still have to check for a non-default value, and exit the scope still, I could use the `IsSuccessful` flag for that. I simply don't want to type those 4 lines every time I call a `ReturnValue<T>` patterned function.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk just have a look at the very last example I gave - this is probably what you want (and mean with scope) - this one will either return the error (if there is already one after evaluating `method()` or will use the retrieved `value` into scope (the block) you can then work with ... so exactly what you are doing)

Comment: If you pimp it up a bit (right now I cannot remember the exact two overloads for `SelectMany` on the top of my head) you can make this work with LINQ also (like `from value in MyMethod() select ...`) - it's just the bind renamed and one more similar function with an additional transformation of the intermediate type LINQ will use

Comment: The caveat to all this is, that C# is not to well equipped to handle the more functional stuff (*don't fear the monads*) but you said yourself that you don't want to discuss your design decisions

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thank you for your effort but I think you get my question wrong, probably because I didn't state it clear enough. See the `edit` section of my question. I'm looking for some C-like macro functionality I guess.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk There's no macros in C#, as simple as that. But do pay attention to Carsten's monadic example - it's very easy to do, and it allows you to easily chain the various `ReturnValue` returning operations together, having different paths for error-values and success-values. See http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/ and http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/ for a great example of the usage (it's in F#, but it works just as well in C#). You're already taking the functional steps - just go all the way and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble :)

Comment: you cannot do *exactly* this - but really the `Bind` I gave you is this with a bit more syntax - what you are trying with the *bubblinig* return is just not possible in C# (it's just what `throw`, `try`, `catch`, ... are for )

Comment: @CarstenKönig +1 For your help!